# Java - Extracting text from string by a common length and prefix

Tags: java, parsing, text

I have a text string " 9926 9928 9951 9953 0 30 57 12 40 54 30"

I am interested in the 4 digit numbers, prefixed by 99. Other numbers are superfluous.

Desired Output:

```
9926
9928
9951
9953
```

My code:

```
String str = " 9926 9928 9951 9953 0 30 57 12 40 54 30";
Iterable<String> result = Splitter.onPattern("99").fixedLength(4).split(str);
```

Actual Output:

```
992
6 99
28 9
951 
9953
 0 3
0 57
 12 
40 5
4 30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) with the regex `99\d{2}`:

```
String str = " 9926 9928 9951 9953 0 30 57 12 40 54 30";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("99\\d{2}").matcher(str);

while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

```
9926
9928
9951
9953
```

See also: [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Note that in regular expressions `\d` is a [predefined character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) equivalent to `[0-9]`. Moreover, `{2}` is a [quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) that means "whatever preceded, twice". So, `99\d{2}` matches two `9`s followed by two arbitrary digits:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZzjFOtMBADucz4uo)

If you're going to be doing this operation with many different strings, consider pre-compiling the regex and storing the `Pattern` instance in some `static final` variable, using that whenever you want to do the operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can go about doing your stuff using the below algorithm.

1. Split your string on `whitespace` character.
2. For each splitted string, check the length. If its 4, you need to further examine that string, else discard it.
3. If the first 2 chars are "99", you can use the [`startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method for this, then it is the number you need.
4. Parse the above string(which satisfied condition 3) into an integer and store it in an array or list.
5. Continue till there are more strings.
6. Display the final array/list, which contains the required items.